# Looking for an alternative SQL statement

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Given the following table with 2 columns:

```
c1      c2  
------------
a1   |  b1 
a1   |  b1  
a2   |  b2
a2   |  b3  
a3   |  b3
```

I want to return those values from column `c2` where the value of `c2` column appears multiple times for the same `c1` value. I am doing the following SQL query to return the required result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ( c2 ) AS c 
  FROM ( SELECT c1 , c2 , COUNT (*) AS rowcount 
           FROM table 
          GROUP BY c1 , c2 HAVING rowcount > 1 )
```

Result:

```
 c
---
 b1
```

Is there any alternative SQL statement of the above query?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: yes. what is your goal? a performance optimization, just a shorter syntax, something wrong with the results?

Comment: Note that your sample data doesn't actually show any such duplicates being present.  Your query is fine, assuming it is performing within your needs.

Comment: Why do you want an alternative, what is your issue with your current query?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT** a function (at least in standard SQL). `distinct a` is the same as `distinct  (a)` and `distinct a,b` is the same as `distinct (a),b` or `distinct a, (b)`

Comment: Your description and sample results are not the same.

Comment: I fixed the issue @Gordon Linoff .

Comment: I edited the sample data. From the sample data, only `(a1, b1)` appears multiple times, so the result will be `b1`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your *description*, you can use:

```
select distinct c1
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by c2) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

Based on your *sample results*:

```
select c1
from t
group by c1
having count(*) >= 2;
```

And based on the *revised* question:

```
select c2
from t
group by c2
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use count in having clause instead of using subquery:-

```
select c1
from table
group by c1
having count(c2) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Most answers above will work if you want all the values in c1 that appear more than once in the table (even with the same value on c2).

If you want to measure only values of c1 that may have multiple DISTINCT values on c2 you can use:

```
SELECT c1 
FROM table 
GROUP BY c1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c2) > 1
```